# Basic Question on Uniswap V2 Swap Math

Tags: uniswap, swaps

I was looking into how swaps for Uniswap V2 worked. I was looking at their [website](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/concepts/protocol-overview/how-uniswap-works) and they showed an example with 3 tokens being swapped into 1. However, I was having some difficulties understanding the example.

They say that the fee for trading is 0.3%, but in the illustration they say that it works out to 0.03 in additional tokens that must be added. Isn't this 3% or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniswap v2 swap fee is 0.3%, the text is correct, the illustrations wrong.

Comment: So just to be clear, 1.003 * 3 = 3.009 should be the total amount added to the pool?

Comment: @Ozzy08 that looks correct.